# What does Deadpool: Secret Invasion cover?

Tags: deadpool

So, what exactly does the Deadpool Vol 1: Secret invasion cover? I have heard this is a good place to start; but, what does it cover?

Is it the original Deadpool series? Is it an independent story line? The same question can be applied to Volumes 2-4 as well. Any insight helps.

Comment: Related, possibly dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116863/what-order-should-i-read-deadpool-tpbs

Answer (score 3):

Are you interested in the Secret Invasion storyline or Deadpool? If it's Secret Invasion you want, I'd suggest starting with Civil War because it leads up to the Secret Invasion story line.

If it's Deadpool you're after, this is as good a place as any to start. But I'd recommend starting with the Civil War arc and reading through to Secret Invasion. And there are successive arcs after that culminating with Avengers Vs. X-Men.

Deadpool is a fun character to read though. So you can start there and dig back or forward as you see fit.

Comment: It is just Deadpool. Haven't gotten an official read order out of anyone. Just trying to figure it out. Thanks for the input.